# How to build tensorflow profiler ui?

Tags: user-interface, tensorflow, build, profiler

I can't find anything about how to build tensorflow profiler ui, but the image of the profiler ui is shown in quick start section  (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/profiler#quick-start).

Comment: I think it's not open sourced yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull https://github.com/tensorflow

and then run this command:

`bazel build tensorflow/core/profiler:profiler`

for tensorflow-ui you can setup:
  https://github.com/tensorflow/profiler-ui

Answer (score 0):

tensorboard has the profiler ui feature. you can check following link

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/experimental/start